# #! Appearing after certain Html Pages on website

Tags: url, web, addition, address-bar

It may be a noob question but is this something to do with my webhost. i go to say www.dgimages.co.nz in the address bar and it brings up the page then the address bar adds /#!/ or on certain html i.e contact.html it adds it to the end like contact.html#!/

Help, is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have certain JS functions on the site, which can be linked with a #, and in your case this is how the menus are working.

Comment: is there any problem with it?

Comment: If the site works as intended, no.